# Python/Eclipse/wxPython -- CallAfter undefined variable? callAfter is as well -- confused

Tags: python, eclipse, wxpython, pydev

I'm using Eclipse Luna and the latest pydev with it.  I have wxpython 3.0 installed.  First, I could import wx and I tried in the console to print **version**, perfect, but then I do import wx.lib.pubsub -- it says unresolved.  I try other variations, no dice, so I have to go into the properties of my project and add wx manually, then it worked.

Second, now all my CallAfter calls are underlined red, undefined variable from import.  I know callAfter used to be it, so I tried that too, it tries to autocomplete to it -- but then underlines it.  I know in 3.0, CallAfter is capitalized.  Even if it wasn't, Eclipse tries to autocomplete to an old version and then says it's still bad.

I've never seen that before, I'm confused.  Does anyone know what I'm doign incorrectly?

EDIT: Even weirder -- I use the console inside pydev eclipse, it autocompletes to normal CallAfter and doesn't throw any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own.  I deleted the wx and wxPython forced builtins and then loaded wx as an external library.  Everything worked fine after that.